# Visual Studio 2013 keeps undoing editor options

Tags: visual-studio

I'm running VS 2013. When I change the color theme from dark (the default) to light (Tools | Options | Environment | General), it does change the color theme. But about 30 seconds later, it changes the color theme back again to dark. Same when I change the font size.

How can I get VS 2013 to keep my settings and not change them back?

Comment: Do you have multiple instances of Visual Studio open?

Comment: No, I'm running only 1 instance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23683446/why-does-visual-studio-2013-keep-changing-to-dark-theme this worked for me, even though only running one instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you have signed into an MSDN account in Visual Studio to enable your license and it is synchronizing your settings globally.

If that is the case then do this:

In VS-2013, go to `Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Synchronized Settings` and then uncheck the "`Enabled synchronization`" box.

That should do it.