# why does visual studio 2013 keep changing to dark theme

Tags: visual-studio-2013, themes

I have visual studio 2013 - professional and it keeps changing my theme from blue to dark.

Anyone have an idea why this is?

Yes, I was logged in with a corporate account that is shared between a couple computers.

Comment: Couple of questions: 1] Are you logged in? 2] Does the shortcut you use to launch VS have any command line parameters?

Comment: yes, i'm logged in with an account that is shared between a couple computers.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It sounds like Synchronized Settings are enabled in your Visual Studio, therefore it is trying to sync theme and other settings across different machines.

Solution: In VS13, go to `Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Synchronized Settings` and then uncheck the "Enabled synchronization" box.

Comment: +1, Thanks, that was driving me nuts, I was sure someone was trolling me, LOL

Comment: Another _"clever"_ feature that constantly bugs out.

Comment: Problem still exists in VS2015 and solution still works the same.

Comment: VS2017, still the same problem, guess you saved a lot of people with this answer...

Comment: Same problem in VS 2019 as well. However, the sync settings are under 
    Environment > Accounts